# Не запускается psql без явного указания host

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian

Ввожу команду `psql` на Debian, получаю ответ:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
   Is the server running locally and accepting
   connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Ввожу команду `psql -h 127.0.0.1` корректно заходит в терминальный клиент `postgre`.

Где и как указать `host`, чтобы при вводе команды `psql` сразу заходило в клиент?

Информация:

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.5

root@psql10:~# uname -a
Linux psql10 4.15.18-7-pve #1 SMP PVE 4.15.18-27 (Wed, 10 Oct 2018 10:50:11 +0200) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: В [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) надо добавить запись типа `local`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кто и как собирал ваш `psql`? Очевидно были скомпилированы разные дефолты, psql собран с поиском дефолтного unixsock в `/tmp`. Этот путь характерен для сборки `postgresql` вручную из исходников, но не характерно для пакетов debian, где обычно используется `/var/run/postgresql/`. Пути к сокетам получаются различные и потому psql подключиться не может.

Соответственно вы можете на выбор:

- пересобрать клиентское приложение с верным значением
- установить пакеты [с репозитория](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/) PostgreSQL Global Development Group
- указать в конфигурации СУБД необходимость создавать сокет так же в директории `/tmp` - это настройка `unix_socket_directories`.